# Creating copy of same product in different stores programmatically?

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I have a scenario where I need to import translations of a product in different stores. At first this product exists in a single store, but after sometime when the translations will be available it has to be in other stores as well but with different information. I am working mainly with the text based fields, and can allow information like price etc to be same for all copies. I have done this previously in `magento-1.9` but I am unable to figure it out yet with `magento-2.1.8`.

I have already tried `setStoreId()` method prior to saving the product but it is not helping much. Along with that I have also used the `setWebsiteIds()` but it will create product in different websites not in stores. Basically what I want is whenever the user select different store views he will get the required information of the product accordingly.

```
$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($targetStoreId);
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->setSku('mysku-' . $targetStoreId)->setAttributeSetId($oldProduct->getAttributeSetId())
            ->setPrice($oldProduct->getPrice());
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $product->setData($key, $value);
        }
        try {
            $product->getResource()->save($product);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());die;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To save a product in Magento 2 I believe you first need to set the scope:

```
 \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
```

the set current store will set the scope in your script:

```
  $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::ADMIN_CODE);
```

or for secondary stores:

```
  $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore(1);
```

I am not sure if you still need to specify -setStoreId($storeId) - perhaps do some testing.

However:

The quickest way to update existing product attributes is to use the attribute update action - this will update to different stores really quickly.  And you don't need to set the scope first.

In your code you'd inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $productAction

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $productAction) {
   $this->action = $productAction;
}

public function updatePerStore($productIds, $data, $storeId) {
    $this->action->updateAttributes($productIds, $data, $storeId);
}
```

The input might be:

```
 $data = ['description' => 'translation_2'];
 $storeId = 1; //whatever store id you like
 $productIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; //whatever product ids you wish to change (note these are ids not skus)
```

Then you'd call it like so:
    $this->updatePerStore($productIds, $data, $storeId);

Apologies for confusion - I can't confirm my code and I am doing from memory..

Comment: So if the product doesn't exists in the target store, by setting the `$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore(<store id of the target store>);` my product will be created in the target store as well?
would you share the working example ? Actually I am  not sure regarding `productRepository` or `productFactory` dependencies to use it with. I have seen numerous of examples on the web but none helped so far.

Comment: Hi, Ali - yes this sets the store scope in Magento 2 so that anything that is saved within the script is saved to that particular store.  In regards to creating products - always best to create in admin first and then update to other stores - but the data will obviously exist in admin store (store 0).

Comment: Added some further info -  Apologies I am not able to code anything at the moment am a bit busy :) - such things as generating your own factories from base classes is one thing you should learn (factory will allow creation of new objects without specifying new <object>  As mentioned best option is to create a new question, perhaps share your code.

Comment: Hi Ali, i have put a quick example of how you would create a product using a factory, then saving via the resource model.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will give it a try and will let you know regarding progress.

Comment: I have used this script and it causing the exception.
`$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($targetStoreId);
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->setSku('mysku-' . $targetStoreId)
            ->setPrice($oldProduct->getPrice());
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $product->setData($key, $value);
        }
        try {
            $product->getResource()->save($product);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());die;
        }`

Comment: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento2`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`
This is the exception I am getting

Comment: if you're creating a product you need to add an attribute set id (sorry my example was just a simple and incomplete pattern of how it can be done) - if you're updating products and not creating then you need to load them first.

Comment: can you add your entire code to the initial post? I think it'd be best idea instead of code in comments.

Comment: I have added the code which I am using so far.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue as it creating new products in the grid, but my requirement is to update the existing product in different store with some data. It is creating the new product as expected making it to go in multiple stores but the old product is still there. Should I remove the old product and keep the new one or there is another way to achieve it?

Comment: Hi Ali - I think there is an issue with understanding here.  When you create a product you assign data to different stores.  It's the same product, there will just be different values recorded in the magento database per store id.  As mentioned, the code I have is incomplete - if trying to create a new product you need to check if the base product exists.  if it does then load it and update, otherwise create it (if creating you need to specify all mandatory fields). I think it's wise to start a new topic with your code, as this topic was about setting a product values against a store.

Comment: Hi Ali, correct - you need to load the old product and set data against it and then save - (the example I made was just to address creating products) - then use the setCurrentStore() to update the different store view data (also you need to confirm that each of your attributes has a scope of storeview)

Comment: Hi Ali, I have updated my post - I think you can better achieve what you need by using the product action update attributes method when updating an existing product. Please see code example, let me know how you go.  Note: You must first assign the product to multiple websites.  Apologies for confusion the initial example was for how to set the scope when updating with the product repository (which you might also like to try)

Comment: I am updating the op to the solution I have used to achieve this. Thanks for you cooperation.

Comment: `$product = $this->productRepository->getById($oldProduct->getId(), true, $oldProduct->getStoreId());
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($targetStoreId);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $product->setData($key, $value);
        }
        $this->productRepository->save($product);`

Comment: hi Ali, that will do it  :)  Glad to help.